# c++ split function randomly crashing

Tags: c++, function, crash

I wrote a function split for c++, because i need it in my program, but it randomly crashes the program. If i keep restarting the same sample program, it sometimes works, sometimes it crashes.

Here is the function:

```
char ** split(char * string, char delimiter, int &num_substrings)
{
num_substrings = 0;

char ** substrings = NULL;
int temp_len = 0;
int string_pos = 0;


substrings = (char **) calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
substrings[num_substrings] = (char *) calloc(1, sizeof(char));

while(string[string_pos] != '\0')
{
    if(string[string_pos] == delimiter)
    {
        num_substrings++;
        substrings = (char **) realloc(substrings, (num_substrings + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        substrings[num_substrings] = (char *) calloc(1, sizeof(char));
        temp_len = 0;
    }else{
        substrings[num_substrings] = (char *) realloc(substrings[num_substrings], (temp_len + 1) * sizeof(char));

        substrings[num_substrings][temp_len] = string[string_pos];
        temp_len++;
        substrings[num_substrings][temp_len] = '\0';
    }
    string_pos++;
}


return substrings;
```

}

And here is how i tested it (the main function):

```
int main()
{
char *s = "1|3|teststring|";
char ** args = NULL;
int num = 0;

args = split(s, '|', num);
cout<<num<<"\n";
cout<<args[0];

}
```

I am compiling it with codeblocks, but with microsoft visual studio is the same result.

Comment: Unless it's for a homework assignment, you should definitely switch to `std::string` and `std::vector`. Chances are you wouldn't even need to ask about that problem :).

Comment: this is more C than C++... how about using std::vector instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: i don't want std::vector, because in my program i will get those substrings, and then reanalyse them to see if they are number, then pass them to a function and so on...it's much more easier for me to work in the way I wanted above

Comment: 1. Please use a debugger first to step through your code. 2. _' but it randomly crashes'_ I'm almost sure this isn't _randomly_, but depends on the actual inputs.

Comment: @user3565078 _'it's much more easier for me to work ...'_ That's hardly believable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question with the function as-is, `temp_len+1` is not large enough because you increment `temp_len` in this code:

```
      substrings[num_substrings] = (char *) realloc(substrings[num_substrings],
           (temp_len + 1) * sizeof(char)); // Allocation here
      // ...
      temp_len++;
      substrings[num_substrings][temp_len] = '\0'; // Invalid write 1 byte after
```

But I concur with using `std::string` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Assuming you can't be convinced to use C++ strings, not C strings: If you have access to a Linux machine, I would recommend that you find these problems with `valgrind`. This is how I located this issue.